# php does not show any mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

## link

```
nt.php?no=
```

## nt.php

```
  <?php
  // Connect to MySQL
  $link = mysql_connect( 'localhost', '********', '*****' );
  if ( !$link ) {
    die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() );
  }

  // Select the data base
$db = mysql_select_db( '***DB***', $link );
  if ( !$db ) {
    die ( 'Error selecting database \'test\' : ' . mysql_error() );
  }

  // Fetch the data
  $query = "
    SELECT * id
    FROM nt where at1='$no'
    ORDER BY id ASC";
  $result = mysql_query( $query );

  // All good?
  if ( !$result ) {
    // Nope
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die( $message );
  }

  // Print out rows
  while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {

    echo  $row['username'];
    echo  $row['name'];

  }

  // Close the connection
  mysql_close($link);
  ?>
```

When I run this script, and host, user pass and db is ok.... but when I try to do like that `nt.php?no=*****` I do not get any info here in        `echo  $row['name']` and also in `$row['username']` option...

Comment: what you got? Have you got any error or not getting records?

Comment: `Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id FROM nt where at1='' ORDER BY id ASC' at line 1 Whole query: SELECT * id FROM nt where at1='' ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: you included flag `java`.

Comment: Where is your `$_GET['no']` call. I doubt that you were not having any `$_GET` instead you were calling directly `$no`

Comment: its my mistake.... because i m totally new here....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before this:

```
// Fetch the data
  $query = "
```

you should add this:

```
$no = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['no']);
```

and replace

```
SELECT * id
```

with

```
SELECT *
```

Answer (score 0):

update in your query

```
$query = "
    SELECT id,username,name,at1
    FROM nt where at1='$no'
    ORDER BY id ASC";
  $result = mysql_query( $query );
```